# Can't find the SHA1 value of my android project. Tried three methods and failed all

Tags: android, gradle, android-keystore

I want get the SHA1 value to use an API. I found three ways to get it.

1. Under C:\Users\username.android there is debug.keystore.
2. Click the Gradle Panel in android studio and find Tasks\Android\signingReport.
3. Use commond line

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

I tried all of them. Here is what I got.

1. No such file. There are only two files under that folder on my laptop, adbkey and adbkey.pub.
2. No such file. I only find two files app\Tasks\other\testDebugUnitTest&testReleaseTest. Nothing more. Even no folder called Android.
3. Error. Terminal tells me keystore doesn't exist.

Update:
1.I found a 'debug.keystore' file in C:\Android.android, that's where I install android studio.
2.In Android stuido, go to Files-> Settings-> Experimental, and uncheck 'Only include test tasks in the Gradle task list generated during Gradle Sync'. Then you need to sync the project. Click the gradle icon next to 'run' zone on the top of android studio. Then, go back to Gradle Tab. Now you can see many folders. Go to Tasks-> android-> signingReport. Double click it. SHA1 will show up in 'run' panel at the bottom.
3. No idea.